# JSON Data log and sent to server

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript function which generates JSON data at every certain second and then PUT it to a cloud server. Now I don't want to POST in realtime, rather I want to log this data in a buffer and say after n number of data log I will PUT to cloud. For example I want to log 50 data point in 10 second and then with timestamp I will PUT to a server

Now JSON data is passed through var fromDatan. JSON data format is

```
{"value":"-2.1282838391939194"}
```

Now the code is:

```
var acc;
    var watchID = null;

function startWatch() {

            //set frequency of accelerometer update.1000 = 1 second

            var options = { frequency: 1000 };
            watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);

        }


    function stopWatch() {
            if (watchID) {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
            }
        }


    //DISPLAY ACCELERATION DATA

    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
            acc = acceleration;
            var element = document.getElementById("accelerometer");
            element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x         + '<br />' +
                              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y         + '<br />' +
                              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z         + '<br />' +
                              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';

                datalock();


        }



    function postdata () {
        var accx = acc.x;
        alert(accx);




            var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                alert(fromDatan);

                //POST JSON  DATA

                $.ajax({
                url: "http://abcd.com",
                headers: {
                    "X-API-KEY": "2b9asdedqedqxdqd7956e6f7a",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                type: "PUT",
                data: fromDatan,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                }
                });
                return false;

        }

        function datalock(){
            alert("Entering");
            fromData.push({
                value: accx.toString(),
            });
            if (fromData.length >= 10) {
                postdata ();
            };

        var fromData;

        }
```

It is not working, although all other things are correct, the pushing I couldn't implement properly. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT START**

Try this:

```
var fromData = [];
var jsonCounter = 0;

function postdata () {
    var accx = acc.x;
    alert(accx);

    var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
    alert(fromDatan);

    $.ajax({
    url: "http://abcd.com",
    headers: {
        "X-API-KEY": "2b9asdedqedqxdqd7956e6f7a",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    type: "PUT",
    data: fromDatan,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, status) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    }
    });
    return false;
}

function datalock(){
    alert("Entering");
    fromData.push({
        value: accx.toString(),
    });

    jsonCounter++;

    // post only after 10 entries
    if (jsonCounter >= 10) {
    postdata ();
    jsonCounter = 0; // reset
    };
}
```

**EDIT END**

Since `JSON` object does not have a `length` property, you can do it by using a variable.

Example:

```
var formdata;
var jsonCounter = 0;

function datalock(){
    alert("Entering");
    fromData.push({
        value: accx.toString(),
    });

    jsonCounter++;

    // post only after 50 entries
    if (jsonCounter >= 50) {
        postdata ();
        jsonCounter = 0; // reset
    };

    //var fromData; // make it global as it is used in other function.
}
```

Comment: I tried with your code, not working, just hitting on "Entering alert . that's it .Not going to function `postdata()` . I am writing the modified code in my answer and let me know if there is any error from my side so that it can be corrected.

Comment: Nothing changed. same thing, not going to post data. just giving alert "Entering" That's it.

Comment: Check the changed code in my answer in this page, this is what I a have changed according to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This is my code so far after modifying it as per suggestion from @web-nomad

```
    function postdata () {
            var accx = acc.x;
            alert(accx);




                var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                    alert(fromDatan);

                    //POST JSON SENSOR DATA

                    $.ajax({
                    url: "http://abcd.com",
                    headers: {
                        "X-API-KEY": "2b9e259asdasd6a7956e6f7a",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    type: "PUT",
                    data: fromDatan,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                    },

                    error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    }
                    });
                    return false;

            //var fromData = {};
            }

            var fromData = [];
            var jsonCounter = 0;

//Edit start

            function datalock() {
            alert("Entering");
            //alert(jsonCounter); //It was showing me only count as 0
            fromData.push({
            value: accx.toString(),
            });
            alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));// no alert
            jsonCounter++;
            alert(jsonCounter); //The alert was not coming at all, when I tried this one
            // post only after 10 entries
            if (jsonCounter >= 10) {
            postdata ();
            jsonCounter = 0; // reset
            };
        }

//Edit End
```

This is the change after your suggestion given @web-nomad

Comment: Any errors on console? Can you log the variables `fromData` and `jsonCounter` after each action?

Comment: @web-nomad Added alert and check the comment on code.

Comment: can you declare these 2 variables right on top, before any function?

Comment: It is already declared outside any function, still did it again on top of all function, at the start of my code. Same problem

Comment: @web-nomad Link for what? the counter is not increasing yet. and it is not going to postdata(). This problem is still there. PUT data has no problem, I checked it with real time data send. My aim is to log multiple data in some array or buffer kind of thing and then send. The multimple data log is not yet achieved.

Comment: All i did was to increment the counter after each `push` and call the `postdata` function only after a certain count was reached...